# Python: How to execute an external program

Tags: python, subprocess

How do I execute a program from within my program without blocking until the executed program finishes?

I have tried:

```
os.system()
```

But it stops my program till the executed program is stopped/closed. Is there a way to allow my program to keep running after the execution of the external program?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Consider using the *subprocess* module.

- Python 2: http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html
- Python 3: http://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html

*subprocess* spawns a new process in which your external application is run. Your application continues execution while the other application runs.

Comment: Unless you explicitly wait for it.

Comment: `os.system` spawns a new process as well - `subprocess` just gives you more control over it.

Answer (score 4):

You want [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 2):

You could use the *subprocess* module, but the os.system will also work. It works through a shell, so you just have to put an '&' at the end of your string. Just like in an interactive shell, it will then run in the background.

If you need to get some kind of output from it, however, you will most likely want to use the subprocess module.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) for that:

```
import subprocess
import codecs

# start 'yourexecutable' with some parameters
# and throw the output away
with codecs.open(os.devnull, 'wb', encoding='utf8') as devnull:
    subprocess.check_call(["yourexecutable",
                           "-param",
                           "value"],
                          stdout=devnull, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT
                          )
```